# Migrating Core Data to React Native Realm

Tags: core-data, react-native, realm

I do have a native app with a Core Data integration. I am writing the same app in React Native and I want to import all the Core Data into the React Native Realm database. I was wondering if this was technically possible.

I have seen ways to do a simple Core Data - > Realm migration, but they were on the Native side. In this scenario, I am using the Realm React Native database.

Comment: Looks like this was answered here https://github.com/realm/realm-js/issues/584

Comment: Yes, I have posted it there too.